# Taking powers of a Vandermonde matrix elementwisely

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a Vandermonde matrix
$$
V (x_1, x_2, \ldots , x_n) =\begin{pmatrix}  1      & x_1    & x_1^2  & \cdots & x_1^{n-1} \\  1      & x_2    & x_2^2  & \cdots & x_2^{n-1} \\  1      & x_3    & x_3^2  & \cdots & x_3^{n-1} \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots    \\  1      & x_n    & x_n^2  & \cdots & x_n^{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
with positive and distinct $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Then it is well-known that $V(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is invertible. It is not hard to see that if we furthermore consider
$$
V_d(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \begin{pmatrix}  1      & x_1^d   & x_1^{2d}  & \cdots & x_1^{(n-1)d} \\  1      & x_2^d    & x_2^{2d}  & \cdots & x_2^{(n-1)d} \\  1      & x_3^d    & x_3^{2d}  & \cdots & x_3^{(n-1)d} \\  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots    \\  1      & x_n^d    & x_n^{2d}  & \cdots & x_n^{(n-1)d}\end{pmatrix},
$$
this is also invertible. This is because
$$
V_d(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = V(x_1^d, x_2^d, \ldots, x_n^d)
$$
and by positivity and distinctness of $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, the values $x_1^d, x_2^d, \dots, x_n^d$ are also distinct.

I am asking myself the following. If we are now given a matrix $V(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)B$ with an invertible matrix $B$, and are taking its power element-wise, is the element-wise power of $V(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)B$ then also invertible? I think so, but I havent found a way to prove it.

Comment: Have you worked out any simple examples. If there are counter-examples they should quickly show up.

Comment: yes i have looked at simploe examples but could not find a counter-example

Comment: I took the element-wise power of any invertible matrix and it campe up invertible too. Maybe it's valid for invertible matrices?

Comment: No, this is not the case, consider for example $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: And couldn't the same thing happen with a combination with a Vandermonde matrix?